# \obj\Debug\res FolderName invalid resource directory name

Tags: xamarin.android, android-resources

I have tried cleaning the project and rebuilding and moving the images to the assets folder and changing the build action. I cannot figure what I am doing wrong

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     obj\Debug\res FolderName    Timer Android   invalid resource directory name

Comment: Please post a complete error message.